# Prove that $T: p(x) =\int_{-\infty}^x f(s)ds\mid p(x), f(x)\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

The question with a solution is #10 on this [PDF](http://www.science.oregonstate.edu/~restrepo/MTH342/HW/HW2Solution.pdf).

I am having trouble seeing where the transformation is defined and understanding how the solution relates to the definition of a linear operator. My understanding is that an operator $L$ is linear if $L(ax+by) = aLx + bLy$, $a,b$ scalars, $x,y$ in $V$ a vector space. I have never seen such a proof (that a transformation is a linear operator) done in this way. I have thought about this question for a long time and can't seem to make any progress on intuition.
Thank you.

Comment: For me,  #10 on the linked PDF seems an unclear problem with a wrong solution.

Comment: Definitely wrong. My guess is that it's _supposed_ to be $p(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(s)\,\mathrm{d}s$, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the responses Michael and Pedro – I thought I was missing something obvious! :)